# Performing loops for first time? Really simple?

Tags: java, loops

I have an assignment with loops that I need help on. It is really quite simple but I don't know how to use loops. I need to print out three shapes using loops. The shapes are made of asterisks, but I'm only allowed to print one asterisk at a time, so I must loops to print the shapes. The first shape is a just 10 asterisks in a row one after another. The second one is just ten lines with one asterisk on each line. The last one is the hardest one. It is a shape that has ten lines. And the first line has one asterisk, the second line has two, the third one has three so on and so forth, then the tenth line has ten asterisks. I tried doing it for the past three hours using my previous assignment but it isn't working out. Here it is:

```
public class assignment9 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (Integer i = *; i >= *; i=i-*) {
            if ((i % *) == *) {
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm taking a computer science class, its for a science credit that I need. I don't plan on being a computer scientist. As you can see, it is not my forte.

Comment: can you add what you managed to get so far?

Comment: Sorry, are the asterisks part of your code, or are they placeholders?

Comment: the asterisk, when they print out, are supposed to make the shape

Comment: Just be careful that the coins don't fall out of your pockets.

Comment: ********** shape one for example

Comment: Holy cow!! Best of luck with your class.

Comment: Whoever wrote that sample doesn't know Java very well. Boxed `Integer`? Seriously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can reason about the third shape. You should be able to figure out the other two, after this, since they are simpler:

You need to print 10 lines. A good way is to count from 0 and move up to 10 (*excluding* 10, otherwise you'd get 11 iterations). You move towards the target by increasing your counter by one (if `i` is your counter, then `i++` increases the count by one). So, at first your variable has a value of 0, then 1, then 2, then 3, then 4, then 5, then 6, then 7, then 8, then finally 9. Here's that part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {         // this means: "repeat 10 times the following"
```

The first line is printed when `i` is 0 and you need to print 1 asterisk for that. The second line is printed when `i` is 1 and you need to print 2 asterisks for that. And so on. So, in general, you need to print as many asterisks as whatever the value of your counter is, plus one (your counter is `i`, so you need `(i + 1)` asterisks). Since you may only print one asterisk at a time, you can repeat `(i + 1)` times the printing of a single asterisk, like this:

```
    for(int k = 0; k < (i + 1); k++)   // this means "repeat (i + 1) times...
        System.out.print("*");         // ...the printing of a single asterisk"
```

Once you've printed all required asterisks for this line, move to the next line:

```
    System.out.println();              // this means "move to the next line"
}
```

And it's over already.

Comment: Why not go from `i = 1` to `i <= 10`? Then you can just use `k < i` instead of `k < (i + 1)`, and the value of `i` would better reflect what it is being used for IMO.

Comment: thank you for your help! But when I did this, as you stated, it just printed the asterisks over and over again?

Comment: @gla3dr True, `i` from 1 up to 10 would be easier for a beginner. But since collection indexes start from 0, I'd feel bad about encouraging iterations starting from 1 if it ends up confusing the reader further in a couple of weeks and they have to change to 0. It's a trade-off, I suppose.

Comment: @THatchick Are you sure you've copied the code correctly? I'm testing it and it only prints 10 lines, as required. Note: I had a typo earlier, if you copied *that*, make sure you copy it as it is now.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis Fair enough. I suppose starting at 0 and stopping at `<` is a good practice to get into.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i<TheAmountOfAsterisks; i++){
  Code for printing out an asterisk
}
```

Edited to provide explanation:

```
for(declarations; condition; action){function}
```

by putting Integer i=0 in, we are declaring a temporary variable called i which can only be used within the loop. The Condition is something that needs to be true for the loop to stop. In this case, as long as i is less than the amount of asterisks, it will keep running the loop. Every time the loop is run, the action will be done - in this case adding 1 to i. Keep in mind that i starts at 0 so it is proper to use a < instead of <=. It will run the loop before doing the action. The function is what you want to do in the loop.